# Chrome redirect to sdsjweb.com

Tags: google-chrome, malware, redirection

I was redirected to https://nuj.sdsjweb.com/f1?s=cf-0&r= by chrome during browsing today. The page displayed a thank you message.

Windows defender is ON and is up-to-date. I scanned the computer once and it didn't find anything. I didn't install any new extension today. Is it some kind of malware? If so how can I remove it.

Chrome Version 51.0.2704.103 m

Windows 10 [Updates enabled]

Answer (score 5):

That is most probably because you typed googe.com instead of google.com

Letter'L' in google is missing.  googe.com will redirect to sdsjweb.

Comment: thanks Kishore. I got redirected to this strange site when accessing google drive. I thought my laptop has been infected with some malware.

Answer (score 2):

Under chrome settings you should find a restore option.  Please note that there could be endless reason to cause this: the most probable is a malware, but you should also check that you are not under a malicious dns or proxy.